# How to provide artifact upload settings in maven

Tags: maven, artifactory

I am using artifactory  for artifacts management .To upload my artifacts to the  server i have below  lines added to my pom.xml

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>e512209f3d01</id>
        <name>e512209f3d01-releases</name>
        <url>http://server-cicd-01-ubt:8081/artifactory/ext-release-local</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>e512209f3d01</id>
        <name>e512209f3d01-snapshots</name>
        <url>http://server-cicd-01-ubt:8081/artifactory/ext-snapshot-local</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

but i do not want these settings to be in pom.xml.Is there any way i can define in global setting.xml. What will be the syntax for that.

Comment: did you check https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Repositories ?

Answer (score 0):

In a similar need, we implemented a **super pom**, which is a single file component (pom.xml only) that declares all common properties and settings to be used by all components developed in our R&D group.

We mostly define common properties like dependencies versions strings and also the  section is there.

Every component needing this needs to declare the super pom as its parent:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>super-pom</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
</parent>
```

This works very well for us for managing 100s of components in the system, which all share common properties.

You can add may common elements like plugins, dependency management etc.

I hope this helps.